# Odd behavior when selecting elements of a Selectable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, selectable, jquery-ui-selectable

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5NekR/5/)

In this Selectable each `<li>` has a nested `<div>`.

```
<ol id="selectable">
    <li>
        <div>
            i love foo
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div>
            bar is awesome
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Now, if I **click** or **ctrl click** an element then the `<li>` gets a `ui-selected` class but the nested div just stays a `ui-selectee`.

However, if I **mouse drag click** then both the `<li>` and the nested `<div>` get the `ui-selected` class.

Why the difference here?  Is it a bug or just something that I am overlooking?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I have the same issue.  I am trying to make a multi level solution, but it only calls the parent level and not the children clicked.

Comment: @fanfavorite I was able to get around the issue but I can't recall exactly what I did.  I just saw your SO question, taking a look now.